# PHP if email is a reply or not

Tags: php

I am using the PHP Function `imap_open` to get emails and insert them into a database.

Whats the best way to see if the email is a reply or not

i have tried:

```
if(!substr($subject,0,3) == 'RE:')
```

to see if the first 3 characters of the subject DO NOT equal *RE:* but that didnt work, i have also tried without the *!* but that didnt work either

any ideas?

Comment: FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291372/know-if-email-was-a-reply-using-imap-in-php

Comment: The correct expression here is `substr(...) != 'RE:'`, but the correct solution to this problem is much more complex. There's no one simple way to detect whether a message is a reply or not.

Comment: He he, you will need a bounce handler for that, is not that easy as you might think. This will help you: https://github.com/twisted1919/bounce-handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo here.

`if(!substr($subject,0,3) == 'RE:')` should be `if(!(substr($subject,0,3) == 'RE:'))`

OR try `!==`

```
if(substr($subject,0,3) !== 'RE:')
```