# Surefire way to know if an email is in reply to an email my mail client sent

Tags: email, smtp

I'm looking for a way to know definitively if an email I receive is in response to a specific email I sent. I manually set the `Message-Id` of the outgoing message using [`make_msgid`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.utils.html#email.utils.make_msgid), store this value, and then check the `In-Reply-To` of an incoming email to determine if it is equal to the original `Message-Id` I sent.

This approach is basically what is suggested here in this [very helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291372/know-if-email-was-a-reply-using-imap-in-php) by Mohammad Eghlima.

But I wonder if this approach is "foolproof" and if there is a better way to accomplish this? For example if there are some clients other than outlook, gmail etc. that do not follow this convention of setting `In-Reply-To` to the `Message-Id` of the original mail for replies, or if they set their own `Message-Id` for some reason (ex. Gmail does this if it determines the existing message id doesn't follow RFC standards)?

I've seen some other answers mention other potential methods to accomplish what I'm trying to do - for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323116/which-headers-are-always-returned-in-a-reply-forward) but most of these questions/answers are from 10 years ago so I'm wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this now.

Answer (score 0):

No, nothing is entirely foolproof. Junior PHP programmers write new email-sending code every day and none of it conforms to any particular set of conventions or RFCs. And then there's Microsoft and Google ... Oh, you are already familiar with them.

There have been no significant developments in email standardization on this particular front in the last decade, so advice from 10 years ago is by and large still relevant.

If anything, the field has been polarized by Microsoft and Google plunging ahead to "innovate" in various aspects of what may charitably be characterized as usability improvements over traditional email, but the motivation has often been to silo in users to prefer or be forced to use their solutions, not standardize anything.

(The efforts to improve e.g. email security through DMARC etc has been better coordinated and standardized.)

The post you link to basically summarizes the information from D. J. Bernstein's excellent email reference resource https://cr.yp.to/mail.html; see in particular the threading conventions at https://cr.yp.to/immhf/thread.html